# Pyautogui LocateOnScreen when it is locatable

Tags: python, pyautogui

I don't know if the title makes any sense but what i want to do is for example a window will pop up in a random time and when it pops up i want to click it.

I tried this code but i knew that it wasn't gonna work:

```
import pyautogui as pt
while True:
    try:
        pt.locateOnScreen(r'E:\projects\test\join.PNG', confidence=.45)
        
    except:
        pass
pt.click()
```

Comment: Try using `tkinter` with `while True` loop, generate random "time" inside for next X seconds and when this time arrives, present the screen

Comment: No, that is not what i meant. Window will pop up by itself what i want to do when it does click on that window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
import pyautogui as pt
while True:
try:
    pt.locateOnScreen('join.PNG', confidence=.45)
    pt.moveTo(position[0], position[1], duration=0.5)
    pt.click()
except:
    pass
pt.click()
```

Comment: or change second (y) position[1] to position[0]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
import pyautogui as pt
while True:
    try:
        pt.click(r'E:\projects\test\join.PNG')
        break
    except:
        pass
```

With PyAutoGUI to click an image you can just pass in the file path to the `click()` function